# Looping through Distinct values in SQL, and using the distinct values in subquery

Tags: sql

I am a bit new to SQL so I would appreciate some help with this.

Say I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
| Manufacturer | ProductName | Price |
|--------------|-------------|-------|
| A            | p1          | 1.00  |
| A            | p2          | 1.50  |
| B            | p3          | 1.00  |
| C            | p4          | 3.50  |
| C            | p5          | 3.50  |
| C            | p6          | 6.00  |
```

How do I loop through the table to return Each manufacturer, the number of products they sell and the average price of the products they sell.  I can do each of these steps in a separate query but I am not sure how to put them all together in a loop.

For example, I know that "SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer from table" will give me a list of all the manufacturers, but then how do I use each of these manufacturers to COUNT the products and AVG the prices?  For Example, I would like to return:

```
Manufacturer   NumberofProducts        AveragePrice
A                  2                     1.25
.
.
.
```

Comment: An advice when working with SQL: don't think in "loops", think in set-based operations (working with all your data all at once). It might be a little misleading at first if you are used to imperative or object-oriented programming, but it's the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use aggregated function with group by

```
select Manufacturer, count(productname) as countofProduct, avg(price) as avgprice
from tablename
group by Manufacturer
```